# How to expose Actuator endpoints with Zuul (no Eureka, Spring Cloud)?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring Cloud app that serves as Zuul Server (with @EnableZuulProxy) annotation. At this stage I have /api/* requests routed to proper middletier services, while all other requests routed to the presentation service, so from the configuration pov it looks like below:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:    
    reservation-owner:
      path: /api/service1
      url: http://service1.net
    --- here couple of other api mappings --   
    ui:
      path: /**
      url: http://presentation-service.net/
```

This works great until I want to check any of the Actuator endpoints on the zuul proxy. Since they fall under the /**, they get routed to the presentation service.

I tried already setting specific endpoints to route to back to the zuul server, but if I am right, I end up with infinite loop of zuul calling itself. So if I am right, I am looking for a way to define path for presentation service that would include everything except of e.g. /admin/* endpoints. Is it possible? Or there is another approach that should be taken?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As soon as you set `/**` zuul swallows all requests. The only way to do it at that point, is to set the [management port](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port).

```
management.port=8081
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I assume it will not fly when the app is deployed in CF environment and ports are anyway managed by CF? :)

Comment: Not when you use `path: /**`. Don't use `/**` and it will work.

Comment: Heh, but how should we then configure Zuul, so that all of the non-api URLs end up at a specific presentation/ui service? Maybe the approach is wrong, but I wonder what is the correct one :)

Comment: Enumerate the ui paths

Comment: Well, this would mean enumerating also all the css'es, images, js'es, etc, isnt it? Would result in a rather long list. Does it mean that in real life actuator simply isnt used with Zuul, or people really list all UI paths in the config.

Comment: Not everyone has a global path (`/**`) on CF.

Comment: And what about assigning management endpoints to a different context path (e.i. management.contextPath=/admin) and then using the following property zuul.ignoredPatterns=/**/admin/**

Answer (score 2):

pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.yml:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Actuator endpoints [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

Comment: Additionally using [base-path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path) parameter might be useful to customise the endpoints paths.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `application.yaml` worked for me to routes and filters endpoints:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'routes,filters'
```